# Comparing 2 string format SIDs

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, active-directory, sid

Can I compare 2 string-format SIDs for equality?

As per my understanding, a Group SID is a unique identifier in an Active Directory forest, so the string that I get by using `ConvertSidToStringSid` will also be unique and can thus be compared to any other Group SID (string format) by using string comparison functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK the answer is "yes as long as you're using case insensitive comparison".

However, if I were you I'd consider using the [EqualSid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446622%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API to compare them as binary, and only convert them to string to show to the end user of your software.